# Howo to check entry.value and change if it contains junk characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

How can i call a function to check the value of {$entry.value} and if it contains "¿" Then remove "¿" and send the rest of the text back.

```
<option value="">Select</option>

<c:forEach var="entry" items="${valuesList}">
<option value="${entry.key}" id=> ${entry.value} </option>
</c:forEach>

function updateValue(selectObj) {
         XXXX
}
```

My real problem is that when i do an AJAX call, junk characters like "Â" are added to "data"

```
jQuery.post("${issuersUrl}", 
        { action : actionSelected, ajax: 'true',"noCache": noCache, "hugxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5430":tokenValue },
        function(data) {
            Query("select#programs").html(data).removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('loading');
        }
    );
```

I tried to find a solution for this but nothing worked. So i thought i can just check entry.value and change it if it has "Â"

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of all special characters or just ones that you have in mind?

Comment: It sounds like the real issue is mismatched string encoding. This article might be of interest: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @jamadri Trying to remove one special character - "Â" which is added when jQuery returns the data. Also, i tried your solution but it didn't work. The data prints as <Employee><name></name></Employee> but data_new becomes EmployeeNameNameEmployee when i do print it in console

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to remove all special characters:

```
jQuery.post("${issuersUrl}", 
    { action : actionSelected, ajax: 'true',"noCache": noCache, "hugxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5430":tokenValue },
    function(data) {
        var data_new = data.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
        Query("select#programs").html(data_new).removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('loading');
    }
);
```

If not, just modify the [^a-z0-9\s] to fit the needs of the characters. Like let's say I want to allow "?" character, just add like so: [^a-z0-9?\s]